# Convert empty DateTime from 01.01.1900 in SQL to null in C# and vice versa

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Our legacy database stores empty Date values as 01.01.1900

I want my application to use 'null' as empty value everywhere by using Converters.

But [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) says that:

> A null value will never be passed to a value converter. This makes the implementation of conversions easier and allows them to be shared amongst nullable and non-nullable properties.

My code:

```cs
var dateConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime?, DateTime>(
  v => v == null ? new DateTime(1900, 01, 01) : v.Value,
  v => v.Year == 1900 ? (DateTime?)null : v);

modelBuilder.Entity<Table>().Property(a => a.Date).HasConversion(dateConverter);

//query
return table.Where(a => a.Date == null);
```

Is translated to:

```sql
select * from table a where a.Date is null
```

I need it to automatically translate to something like:

```sql
select * from table a where a.Date = '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'
```

Is there any workaround for null values in Converters?

Comment: That's neither empty nor null. That's a perfectly valid DateTime either in the SQL Server or C#

Comment: why do you use this as a special value? why not make the column nullable which is a non-breaking change

Comment: Why are you trying to change a valid value into `null`? Where did this value come from? Some table field default? Perhaps that field should be *nullable* instead of accepting meaningless defaults?

Comment: Can you compare `a.Date = DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: @dvo DateTime.MinValue is 0001-01-01. 1900-01-01 is a perfectly valid value, not empty or "zero"

Comment: @dvo `DateTime.MinValue` is `01/01/0001 00:00:00` not `01/01/1900 00:00:00`

Comment: Our legacy database stores empty Date values as 01.01.1900. I can not change this fact.

Comment: I'll have to repeat this - 1900-01-01 is a *perfectly* valid value that can appear in any database. Using it as a default is as ... suboptimal as picking 2000-01-01 as a default. If the date is missing, the field should be nullable and have a `null` value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and phuzi - My bad. Read his date wrong.

Comment: @xiety what legacy database? Which product which version? In any case, that value is valid. Not empty, not null. At best someone used it as a "magic" value.

Comment: @dvo Yes, DateTime.MinValue is working as required when I rewrite Converter to support this. But 'null' is more explicit.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, this is some magic value. This is Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009

Comment: @xiety in that case are you sure you understand what that value is for and how it's used? Most likely it's *not* an empty value but something small enough to fall outside range queries. Treating it as "empty" or "null" is wrong. It's not *empty*, it's *smaller than any expected value*. Treating it as null is simply wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos old app just shows an empty input box for this value, and datenull() method returns 01.01.1900, so I am sure.

Comment: @xiety this means that either you should *use* those fields the way they are, or use a [Global Query Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters), not a value converter to eliminate unwanted results. I suspect the correct treatement is to just use the values though

Comment: @xiety that proves nothing at all, unless it's confusion between  X++ and the database, which is SQL Server. There's no `datenull()` in SQL Server or C#. `01.01.1900` is a localized string - SSMS would display dates in ISO8601 format. What do the *tables* contain?

Comment: can't you simply treat your queries as `a.Date > '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'`, making sure you "treat" such value as non existing?

Comment: @balexandre there may not be any reason to do so, the OP mentions X++ functions and values, not what is actually stored in SQL Server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the field in SQL is [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL, with DEFAULT ('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I thought that ORM like EF Core can give me the ability to setup mapping from different values. Global Query Filter will not help me with quering, updating and inserting tables with such fields through all application. Sometimes I need to select Date == null, sometimes Date != null. Converters looks like the ideal solution, but only if they could support null.

Comment: @xiety, check if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values) works for you

Comment: @Matt.G, no HasDefaultValue doesn't help me to convert null to specific value in queries

Comment: @xiety don't do that at all. You aren't mapping values, you're trying to change SQL's (the language) three-valued logic and SQL itself. NULL in SQL isn't just another value, it has very specific meaning. It requires *different syntax*. When you say you need to select `Date == null` that's translated to `Date is null`, not `Date=null`. Converters are completely inappropriate for this, you need to change the generated SQL itself. And even *that* wouldn't handle outer joins.

Comment: @xiety instead of trying to change how SQL works (and having to deal with confusion and bugs when even *you* forget it's changed behind the scenes), define an `Empty` date somewhere, eg an `AX.Empty` constant,  and use that for comparisons.

Comment: I've found "Allow HasConversion/ValueConverters to convert nulls" in an EF Core Backlog https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/milestone/2